# Crystal Report displaying Ys at random in place of number 0

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report that runs off of a database view. The view's data is clean, but occasionally this report will place Y's throughout the document in locations where 0 is. Sometimes every 0 is replaced with a Y, but other times Y's only show up a few times or not at all. This is on a load balanced system between two Windows servers so that could be the issue, but the Y's only show up <10% of the time. When it does happen, we've re-run the report and it prints out fine. This report runs several times a day and is completely unpredictable. It just started happening recently but the report hasn't been altered in almost a year, and on seemingly identical installations this problem does not occur.

Further information: I have found that occasionally if the incorrect location of usp10.dll is running the font may cause the Y's, but that doesn't explain why sometimes only a few show up. Also that occurs mostly with Calibri while my report is using Courier New. This problem only occurs when printing and now when rendered as PDF. I use Crystal Reports 2008 on Windows, the data comes from an Oracle DB, and it is interacting with load balanced UNIX servers.

UPDATE: I amended the title and body to show that Y's are actually replacing the number 0, not blank spaces as previously mentioned. The seemingly identical installations have just had this problem reported. There is still one system that has not been updated in a while that has it unreported though.

Comment: Which system(s) are rendering the document in PDF?  Is it the windows or the UNIX?

Comment: CR is only installed on the Windows servers, and it renders the PDFs as well as prints the reports.

Comment: Did both servers get the patch that fixed the low-security string processing function(that happened in the last couple months)?  Can you reinstall the fonts from the good server to the bad server?  If you run AscW() on the space character and the Y character, does the output of that function change when it's a bad run?  Sorry if these questions waste your time, but this problem is interesting to me...

Comment: No, thank you! I'll check all those things.

Comment: I just found out it is actually replacing the number 0 with Y on those occasions. I also have run about 40 through a different printer and haven't encountered any issues. I can't run AscW() on them at this time, but I'll check when I can. I have replaced the fonts with ones from the good server and am awaiting verification.

Comment: Reinstalling the fonts doesn't fix it. We've had success on one printer but not another so we're attempting other printer tests to confirm printer-related error.